# "Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor" getting error in Java code?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I am getting two errors in this code

1. Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor.
2. Implicit super constructor Parent() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor.

So please help me to resolve these issues.

```
class Parent
{
  public Parent(int x, int y,int z)
  {
    System.out.println("Created Parent");
  }
}
public class Child extends Parent
{
  Child(int x)// error 2   
  {

  }
  Child(int x, int y)// error 2
  {
  }
  Child(int x, int y, int z)
  {
    this(x);
    super(x,y,z);// error 2
    System.out.println("Creating child");
    this(x,y);// error 1
  }
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Child c=new Child(1,2,3);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the first error is very very very clear.. The second is very clear.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is in the question. You have to call parent class constructor before any other statement in child class constructor.

```
public class Child extends Parent
{
Child(int x)// error 2   
{
   super(0,0,0);
}
Child(int x, int y)// error 2
{
   super(x,y,0);
}
Child(int x, int y, int z)
{
 super(x,y,z);

 System.out.println("Creating child");

}
```

call to base constructor is not mandatory if base has a default constructor, this is not the case in your code.

The theory behind this is, in any inheritance hierarchy, when you instantiate any derived object, first the top most base will be initialized, then next of it and so on upto the actual derivation point.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing a constructor has to do is to invoke the parent class constructor.

The implicit default is `super()` (without any arguments), but that does not work in your case, because the parent class `Parent` does not have a no-arguments constructor, it only has one with three int arguments, so you need to invoke that one.

And you need to do that in the first line of the constructor.

Instead of calling the super constructor, you can also call another constructor (another `this()`) on the same class. The super constructor is assumed to be called by that other constructor (otherwise it would not compile).

But you have to call `this()` also in the first line of the constructor.

And after you have called `this()` or `super()`, you cannot call it a second time.

---

```
 Child(int x)// error 2   
 {

 }
```

Does not compile, because there is no `super()` to match the implicit call.

```
Child(int x, int y)// error 2
{
}
```

Same problem.

```
Child(int x, int y, int z)
{
  this(x);
  super(x,y,z);// error 2
  System.out.println("Creating child");
  this(x,y);// error 1
}
```

You cannot call `super()` or `this()` except on the very first line.

Answer (score 2):

There are four things you need to understand:

- If you don't specify *any* explicit constructor call, the compiler inserts a call to `super()` for you.
- There must be *exactly one* constructor call for any constructor- either explicit or the implicit `super()` call. (You've got three in your `Child(int, int, int)` constructor.
- An explicit constructor call must be the very first statement in the constructor body.
- You can only call a constructor which actually exists - so a call to `super()` from `Child` is looking for a parameterless constructor in `Parent`, which doesn't exist.

One frequent pattern is to have a "master" constructor which other constructors in the same class chain to, and then that one chains to the superclass. For example:

```
Child(int x)
{
    this(x, 0); // Chains to the Child(int, int) constructor, defaulting y to 0
}

Child(int x, int y)
{
    // Chains to the Child(int, int, int) constructor, defaulting z to 0
    this(x, y, 0);
}

Child(int x, int y, int z)
{
    super(x, y, z);
    System.out.println("Creating child");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new instance of Child class first thing to do is to call super(x,y,z), otherwise it cannot works. In fact a Child "is a" Parent, so to have an instance of Child you must be able to instantiate superclass. So Child(int x){ super(x,0,0);} is a possible constructor for Child class, but Child(int x){} isn't because Parent class does not have the default constructor.  Remember that when you explicitly add a constructor to your class the default one is no more available. Finally, the constructor you wrote: Child(int x, int y, int z){this(x); super(x,y,z); this(x,y);} cannot works, because in a constructor you call three different constructors, but how many instances would you like to have? You can create just one instance per contructor.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a child object, the order of calling constructor is 
Parent ---> followed by Child. 
So The first line in your constructor has to be a call to the parent constructor. ( If you don't provide yourself, the compiler will insert one for you.) OR a call to own overloaded constructor (which will call super as explained above).

Your error 1 is caused because you have called the constructor only after certain executable statement are executed.

For error 2...
First thing you must know is that , a compiler will provide a default no-arg constructor  for every class IF YOU DON'T PROVIDE ANY TYPE OF CONSTRUCTOR AT ALL.

But the moment , you provide a constructor , compiler no longer gives you a default constructor. you need to write one by yourself.

Second thing, by default , if you don't have a super() in your child class, the compiler will put by default a no-arg call to super().

This is where your problem lies.

You have given a parametrized constructor for your parent , and so compiler didn't provide with a no-arg default constructor. And now when in your child class you dont put your own super(xy,z) call, it will put a default no-arg super() call. BUT THE PARENT DOENST HAVE A NO AGR CONSTRUCTOR....hence the error.

You can do 2 things to solve this, either write a
    Parent() {}

constructor

or put an explicit call to super  --> 
super (0,0,0)
in each child constructor